# How can I test and debug at chrome for Android App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have made a simple android app using ionic and AngularJs and I run this app then it works in a a browser while I run app in Emulator then it is not working.So I want to find issue what is reason that it is not working so for this purpose I want to do testing  and debugging

I have made a simple android app using Ionic and AngularJS and whenI run this app then it works in a browser while I run this app in Emulator then it is not working.

Please tell me how can I test and debug in a chrome for android app.And also  tell me detail with step.

Answer (score 0):

You can [build the app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build/) in debug mode and then connect your computer to your Android phone that you want to test the app. After that, you install the app via the `.apk` that you just generated then start the app. Now that your app is running in your phone that is connected to your computer, you can debug via Google Chrome by inspecting it. [Here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) is how to do so in details.